# Scala type mismatch with variable args

Tags: scala

I've noticed that every time I try to do declare a class or case class with parameters like so:

```
class X(op: (Int, Int) => Int, i: Int*) {}

val x = X(_ + _, 5)
```

This gives me a type mismatch error, but if I add another int argument like so:

```
val x = X(_ + _, 5, 7)
```

This works fine. I should note that I also don't get any errors if my first parameter is not a function. I can easily define:

```
class X(c: Char, i: Int*)

val x = X('c', 5)
```

And I get no compilation errors. Does anyone know why this is happening? And if so, how could I go about passing only 1 Int in my argument?

Comment: `new X(_ + _, 5)` compiles and runs for me. No errors. What Scala version are you using?

Comment: Actually the way you are instantiating or creating the object for a class is wrong right? you don't need a new only for case-classes, but it's required for a normal class.

Comment: Ok so, I realized that the error only comes up when using case classes

Comment: `val x = new X(_ + _, 5)` works, but with a case class and `val x = X(_ + _, 5)` does not

Comment: Wait. Declaring val x with new X instead of X, even with a case class, works but X.apply does not. What the heck is going on

Comment: `case class X(...)` with `X.apply(_+_, 5)` still works for me.

Comment: Did you get that error in the IDE? it is working for me in the REPL (apply and new)

Comment: Yeah. My IDE is Intellij. X(_ + _, 5) and X.apply(_ + _, 5) don't work when X is a case object

Comment: If it works in REPL then it must just be some sort of IDE error

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the exact code that causes the error?

Comment: `_ + _` is not the same thing as either `_ +` or `+ _`. Hopefully that just means that your posted comments are getting sloppy. (There is a 5 minute window, after posting, in which a comment can be edited/corrected.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. In all of the cases you posted, I would expect to get an error that `X` cannot be found, and in fact, when I copy&paste your code, I *do* get that exact error: `error: not found: value X`. I never get the error you are claiming to get, and the code you claim does work, also produces the same error.

Comment: I apologize for not replying sooner. The exact code is the following:

    `case class X(function: (Int, Int) => Int, i: Int*)`
    `val x = X(_ + _, 5)`

This gives me a type-mismatch error. However, changing it to:

    `case class X(function: (Int, Int) => Int, i: Int*)`
    `val x = X(_ + _, 5, 3)`

Works fine